# Mysql return the row position with sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

the ff table:

```
+-----------------------------+
+ value| name   |Asort        +
+-----------------------------+
+  111 | Alpha  |a            +
+  161 | Beta   |b            +
+  092 | Delta  |c            +
+  141 | Beta   |a            +
+  113 | Beta   |e            +
+  092 | Delta  |f            +
+  ...                        +
+  ... | more items           +
+-----------------------------+




+-----------------------------+
+ value| name |Asort          +
+-----------------------------+
+  141 | Beta |a              +
+  161 | Beta |b              +
+  113 | Beta |c              +
+  ...                        +
+  ... | more items(Beta)     +
+-----------------------------+
```

i want a return of "3" as "113" row position that where group by name Beta and sort ASC by Asort

Comment: And the order is? And don't say the order the data was inserted.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what exactly you want and what you are trying to do

Comment: i have that table above (tbl1). then sort it by group with name of beta, and then i will find the postion row/index of the value 113.

Comment: With what you've presented here you're kindof asking a non-question.  In the table that you've presented (the ff table) either the value field IS your index, or you don't have an index.

Since you can sort and reorder tables in whatever way you want, finding that a value is the "3rd" value when you search in a particular order isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: no. im looking for nested query. i dont need index for this

Comment: Hello mon-sun welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer much faster – Also 
please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
And for sql questions please include your rdbms and data sample with input and desire output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use a variable to calculate rank ([*row-number-in-mysql*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)) because mySql doesnt have `ROW_NUMBER`.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/936b4/2)

```
SELECT ff.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM ff, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE name = 'Beta'  
ORDER BY Asort
```

Comment: this one is works for me, can i use "rank" as OFFSET in LIMIT at one query only?

Comment: can you elaborate what you want?